# Error applying matrix transformation to an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have this transformation matrix and now I need to apply it to an image. I tried with imwarp (A, T) where A = imread ('image.jpg') and T is the following matrix transformation:

```
    0.3669    0.2443    0.0011
    0.4114    0.3224    0.0013
   -325.0508 -243.0855  1.0000
```

But gives me this error:

```
Error using imwarp>parseInputsDisplacementFieldSyntax (line 358)
The value of 'DisplacementField' is invalid. Displacement field D must be
of size MxNx2 or MxNxPx3.

Error in imwarp (line 156)
    parsedInputs = parseInputsDisplacementFieldSyntax(varargin{:});

Error in Untitled2 (line 66)
B=imwarp(A,transformada2)
```

Comment: How did you create `T`?

Comment: More importantly, did you use `affine2d` to create the `tform` object required by `imwarp`?

Answer (score 1):

`imwarp` does not take the transformation matrix directly. It takes a transformation object, which can be of type `affine2d` or `projective2d`. So you should first create an `affine2d` object from your matrix, and then pass that to `imwarp`.